# PDF is not rendered fully on the new tab in the web browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The PDF is not rendered on a full page, instead, it is rendered within a frame link window as you see on the below screenshot. When I refresh the same, it opens the full page.
I am not using iframe or anything like that. Please suggest. Below is my code.

```
<a href="#"  onClick={() => fetchAPdfFile("dummy.pdf")} rel="noopener noreferrer"> Test.pdf</a>
```

fetchAPdfFile.jsx

```
  const fetchAPdfFile = (myPdf) => {
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  var response = pullMyPDf(myPdf) //byteArray stream from api
  var bytes = base64ToArrayBuffer(response.data)
  const blob = new Blob([bytes], 'application/pdf')
  anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(anchor.href, '_blank')
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the javascript code or HTML that posted in my question. The PDF was shown in a frame instead of full view is because one of my content security policy was set to not allow some style elements specific to my application. I just allowed them and the page shows PDF in full view